# How to add a device to an internal tester in TestFlight?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, device, testflight

I have a new device that I already registered in my Apple Developer account. In iTunes Connect I can see the list of my associated devices, but I don`t find the way to edit such list and add my new device. I don't either find in the documentation how to do this, could somebody tell me how could I add a new device to my iTunes Connect profile for TestFlight internal testing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to add a device for testing through TestFlight, only email addresses. For internal testers the user should have a role in iTunesConnect. If you want to add a device for Ad-Hoc deployment, you will need to update in the developer console and add it to the app's development provisioning profile.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to add the device. If you login to iTunesConnect, go to Users&Roles -> Testflight-BetaTesters -> Internal. There you should see the person you added.

Once your tester has accepted the invitation in the email you can go to Apps -> YourApp -> Prerelease. Then add him. Your tester needs to download Testflight from the AppStore and login. That should work, then he installs the app to test.

Comment: We're not seeing that adding someone as an internal tester sends an invitation? Adding them as a developer role automatically added them as an internal tester, but no email.  Was it supposed to? Or are we missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

After they are added as an Internal Tester under Users and Roles, you must go to the TestFlight tab **within each app**, click on iTunes Connect Users, tap the plus sign and select them from the list of users and click Add.  Then they will get the email invitation.